# Convert latitude and longitude to utm point in 43 Zone

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, arcgis, arcgis-server

I have latitude and longitude points like(23.7019973789308,72.5465551902882)
like this, I have many point, who are enter by Users in my application,
I just want to convert them in Meters in 43 Zone in C#.
I did't get any suitable code, who can convert these points.
I go through this link also, but did't get solution.
http://www.igorexchange.com/node/927

I tried this code also....

```
  static public IPoint FromLatLonToUTM(double lon, double lat, out double UTM_x, out double UTM_y)
  {
  ISpatialReferenceFactory2 pSpatRefFact;
  IProjectedCoordinateSystem pToPCS; 
  IGeographicCoordinateSystem pFromGCS; 
  IGeometry pGeo ; 
  IPoint pPoint;

  UTM_x = 0;
  UTM_y = 0;

  pPoint = new PointClass();
  pPoint.PutCoords(lon, lat);

  pSpatRefFact = new SpatialReferenceEnvironmentClass();

  pFromGCS = pSpatRefFact.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem((int)esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_NAD1983);
  pToPCS = pSpatRefFact.CreateProjectedCoordinateSystem((int)esriSRProjCSType.esriSRProjCS_NAD1983UTM_17N);

  pGeo = pPoint;
  pGeo.SpatialReference = pFromGCS;

  pGeo.Project (pToPCS);

  pPoint = (IPoint) pGeo;
  UTM_x =  pPoint.X;
  UTM_y = pPoint.Y;
          Debug.Write(UTM_x);
          Debug.WriteLine("");
          Debug.Write(UTM_y);
          Debug.WriteLine("");
  return  pPoint;
}
```

Help me.............

Comment: Three things: 1) Are you sure you should be using NAD1983 for your source CS? Where are your source lat/longs coming from? 2) If you're trying to convert to UTM Zone 43N, why are you using `esriSRProjCS_NAD1983UTM_17N`? 3) Why are you using a North American projection for data which appears (from your example coordinates) to be in India?

Comment: old question but for anyone who stumbles across it, you might want to try posting on gis.stackexchange.com